# Python3 + How to change the output color when using print command

Tags: python, python-3.x, linux, tput

as maybe some of you know and regarding to shell scripts - `tput` is utility uses the terminfo database to make the values of terminal-dependent capabilities and information available to the shell

in my python script I have the following example: ( just a sample from long code )

```
for TOPIC in list:
  if str(val) in TOPIC:
     word = TOPIC.split()[1]
     print ("Topic " + word + " is successfully configured")
  else:
      try:
       word = TOPIC.split()[1]
       print ("Topic " + word + " bad configuration")
      except IndexError:
       pass
```

I want to change the color from white to **green** on the following printing:

```
 print ("Topic " + word + " is successfully configured")
```

or to change the color from white to **red** on:

```
print ("Topic " + word + " bad configuration")
```

is it possible to change the **color** in `python3` as we did for example in `bash` scripts?

Comment: Check [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/287871/how-to-print-colored-text-to-the-terminal) for help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import os
os.system("")

RED = "\x1B["
GREEN = '\033[32m'

word = "random_topic_name"
print(GREEN+"Topic " + word + "successfully configured" )
print(RED+"Topic " + word + "bad configuration" )
```